# "Migrate to Spring Boot 3.2" recipe fails on Lombok Java16 related issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, openrewrite

Project: Spring Boot 2.7.11, Java11

Lombok dependency as following

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
```

---

Attempting to run: ["Migrate to Spring Boot 3.2"](https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot3/upgradespringboot_3_2)

Active java version when running: Java11

---

The following error (related to Java 16, JEP 396: Strongly Encapsulate JDK Internals by Default) occurs:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x2fbe1acc) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x2fbe1acc
```

Workaround: first run "Migrate to Java17" recipe (which results in successful upgrade of Lombok) and only then run "Migrate to Spring Boot 3.2".

---

Is it a bug in OpenRewrite or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi! When do you get that error? Is that during or after a run?

Comment: Note that after the run you should switch to using Java 17, as required by spring boot 3

Comment: @Tim Getting it when running "gradle rewriteRun"

Comment: That's surprising; not sure if that's something we can do much about; Does it help if you either run from Java 17 to start with, or only upgrade Lombok before you run the recipe?

Comment: I'm mostly looking for something that gets you going; as I don't think there's much we can do from OpenRewrite to help this along.

Comment: @Tim There are several workarounds I found (for example: running Java17 recipe first, upgrading Lombok version manually and then running Spring Boot 3 recipe).
I managed, but I would like other people at my team who also need this recipe to be able to use it out of the box.
But it seems that Spring Boot 3 recipe doesn't work as expected when Lombok upgrade is required. Since Java17 recipe works as expected and Java17 recipe is part of Spring Boot 3 recipe it seems something in the order of steps in Spring Boot 3 recipe is the issue.
Is there a way to reach to recipe authors?

Comment: Understandable, and yeah sure you can open up an issue here and we'll have a look: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/issues/new/choose